# Draw over a bitmap loaded in a picturebox

Tags: c#

I need to draw over a bitmap loaded in a `PictureBox`. I've been looking for a way on this site but the answers don't work because the resulting image is in a wrong location.

```
private void pbImage_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    currentImage = pbImage.Image;
    Bitmap imageAux = new Bitmap(currentImage.Width, currentImage.Height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imageAux))
    { 
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 10);
        g.DrawImage(currentImage, pbImage.Location);
        g.Flush();
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Control control = (Control)sender;
            punto = ((Control)sender).PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y)); ;

            g.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(punto.X, punto.Y, 50, 50));
            g.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(punto.X, punto.Y, 50, 50));
            g.Flush();
            g.Dispose();
            pbImage.Invalidate();
        }
    }
    pbImage.Refresh();
    currentImage.Save("C:\\prueba3.bmp");
    imageAux.Save("C:\\prueba4.bmp");
    pbImage.Image = (Image)imageAux.Clone();
}
```

Comment: `using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imageAux))` and `g.Dispose();` should not be combined. it's one or the other.

Comment: Use `0, 0` coordinates instead of `pbImage.Location`.

Comment: But that will draw the image into de picturebox location? thank u!!

Comment: Is the image loaded in the picturebox? or do you use the picturebox te show a bitmap

Comment: I need to edit an image loaded in the picturebox to store it later in a bd. I use imageAux because I have read that it is the only way to use graphics, I can't use my currentImage because of the format. Thanks

Comment: The purpose is not completely clear. What should it do?

Comment: The bitmap is a mask (black&white image) which determines the zone to be inspected in the real image (white zone). I would like to paint that mask and add more black to the image. The purpose is modificate that zones, like a 'paint brush'. ¿Do you understand? Sorry about my English, I'm doing my best :S

Comment: Without knowing the SizeMode of the PictureBox we can't see the error.

Comment: It is StretchImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create additional Bitmaps to draw.

- Load the original in a Bitmap.
- Create a bitmap to assign to the picturebox. *(backpage)*
- Create/Generate a grayscale version of the original bitmap.

When it needs to draw:

- Clear the picturebox bitmap
- Draw the grayscale onto
- Draw the 50, 50 rect of the original on the selection location in the picturebox bitmap
- Refresh het picturebox

Here's an example, Add a picturebox to the Form and replace the filename with your image filename.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Bitmap _originalBitmap;
    private Bitmap _grayScaleBitmap;
    private Bitmap _pictureBoxBitmap;

    //private Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
    private Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    private Point? _inspectRectStart;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _originalBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("lin-png-256x256-Rafael_256x256_png-256x256.png");
        _grayScaleBitmap = MakeGrayscale3(_originalBitmap);

        _pictureBoxBitmap = new Bitmap(_originalBitmap.Width, _originalBitmap.Height);
        DrawImage();

        pictureBox1.Image = _pictureBoxBitmap;
    }

    private static Bitmap MakeGrayscale3(Bitmap original)
    {
        //create a blank bitmap the same size as original
        Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);

        //get a graphics object from the new image
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap);

        //create the grayscale ColorMatrix
        ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(
           new float[][]
           {
             new float[] {.3f, .3f, .3f, 0, 0},
             new float[] {.59f, .59f, .59f, 0, 0},
             new float[] {.11f, .11f, .11f, 0, 0},
             new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
             new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
           });

        //create some image attributes
        ImageAttributes attributes = new ImageAttributes();

        //set the color matrix attribute
        attributes.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix);

        //draw the original image on the new image
        //using the grayscale color matrix
        g.DrawImage(original, new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height),
           0, 0, original.Width, original.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);

        //dispose the Graphics object
        g.Dispose();
        return newBitmap;

    }
    private void DrawImage()
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_pictureBoxBitmap))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.White); // if the bitmap has transparent parts

            // draw the grayscale image.
            g.DrawImage(_grayScaleBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, _originalBitmap.Width, _originalBitmap.Height), 0, 0, _originalBitmap.Width, _originalBitmap.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            // if there is a selection, draw it.
            if (_inspectRectStart.HasValue)
            {
                var rect = new Rectangle(_inspectRectStart.Value, new Size(50, 50));

                // draw the original bitmap in a rectangle.
                g.DrawImage(_originalBitmap, _inspectRectStart.Value.X, _inspectRectStart.Value.Y, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
            }
        }

        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // move the rectangle position
        _inspectRectStart = e.Location;
        // redraw image.
        DrawImage();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for you time... I have one cuestion, the bitmap I'm loading in the picturebox is variable. I mean, the form has some controls (combobox) and depending on the selection, the propierty Image from the picturebox is read from data base or a directory. Is it necessary initialize the component?

Comment: You should not assign an image/bitmap to the picturebox directly. You should load/draw the image into the `_originalBitmap`

Answer (score 0):

I think, thats because `g.DrawImage(currentImage, pbImage.Location);` will draw the image relative on the `imageAux` with the actual location of the pbImage in relation to it's parent. try `new Point();` instead.

Comment: I have tried and the image is at the right location, but I can't see the draw of the rectangle :S Thanks!